# Pythonでplusoneのカウント数取得する方法

Tags: python

以下のサイトの記事の右下にplusoneのカウント数が表示されていますが、この数字を取得したいです。
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zaaa&hl=ja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず目的の要素をブラウザの開発ツールで調査します。
すると、G+のボタンは生成された`iframe`の中に入っている事が分かります。
`iframe`の`src`を見ると、パラメータがいろいろありますが、必要そうなのは`url`だけです。
`url`だけ残すとこの様になります。
https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.android.com%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.nintendo.zaaa

後はこれをGETしてスクレイピングすればよいです。
数字の部分は`id="aggregateCount"`ですね。

Comment: でもこのIDのタグはJavaScriptで生成しているのでは？GETするだけでは無理な気がします

Comment: ＠KenjiNoguchi いえ、サーバ側で生成されています

Comment: まあ「今は」ですが。公開されたAPIでなければ将来はあてになりませんね。

Comment: 試してみました。確かにサーバー側でした！この手の「いいね」ボタンのせいである個人がどんなサイトを訪問しているのか筒抜けですね。